# How to disable a specific store app temporarily without uninstalling on win 10/11 pro?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

I want to disable a specific store app without uninstalling it so i can re enable it when i need it without wasting much time to install it from scratch.

Any registry tweak or 3rd party app to achieve this possible? Appreciate helps thanks.

Edit: Specific goal here; there are 2 apps installed from same vendor, one is store app other one is non store (installed to program files). Non store app is refusing to open while store one is installed. Uninstalling/reinstalling store app is not practical and takes some time. I thought if i can disable the store app (show it like its not installed, not exist) then it could be a workaround. The app is probably looking at registry, programs list or folder path maybe. There is no environmental variables so shouldnt be there.

Is there a common way/place on Windows 10/11 that 3rd party applications check to see if any particular store app is installed?

Comment: To what end. . ?

Comment: You can try GPO: https://www.technipages.com/prevent-users-from-running-certain-programs/ . Without specific info, that's just a WAG.,

Comment: Based on your comments on the answer given, it sounds as though you'd need to understand what, specifically, the app/program are detecting about each other, or the mechanism they use to detect each other, in order to choose the best/simplest way to switch between them. Does the publisher of this program give any indication how they detect this? Is there any error message/code given or written to Event Viewer or another app-specific log when you attempt to run the one that doesn't work?

Comment: @music2myear  thats the point you are right, thats what im trying to understand as i have no idea how 2 apps know each others existence (actually only non store app is refusing to start while store one is installed). There is no any related logs from apps or event viewer. I was wondering about common places on windows 10/11 where apps look up other apps, particularly for store apps i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can't enable or disable one specific app. You may either
uninstall and reinstall the app, or you more simply remove
from the app some essential permission it requires,
in effect making it impossible for the app to function.

Disabling and enabling permissions for a Store app is done in
*Settings > Privacy*. You may here click on the left on a permission,
to see all the Store apps that are registered as requiring it.
You may here disable or enable the app use of this permission.

Comment: Goal here; there are 2 apps installed from same vendor, one is store app other one is non store (installed to program files). Non store app is refusing to open while store one is installed. Uninstalling/reinstalling store app is not practical and takes some time. I thought if i can disable the store app (show it like its not installed, not exist) then it could be a workaround. The app is probably looking at registry, programs list or folder path maybe. There is no environmental variables so shouldnt be there. Maybe renaming/removing a key in registry, a folder/file etc will achieve this?

Comment: This is not practical for the reason that the two instances are probably fighting over common resources such as registry keys. You say: "Non store app is refusing to open while store one is installed". I would say that one instance has modified an essential key, therefore disabling in effect the other. I would suggest going back to a clean state by uninstalling *both* instances, first the Store app and then using Revo Uninstaller Free for the other. Then install only one instance.

Comment: Point is ability to use both apps when needed, one at a time, without going through uninstall/reinstall cycle everytime.

Comment: It's probably impossible to do because of conflicts. You'll need to isolate one app in its own little world, for example using [Sandboxie Plus](https://sandboxie-plus.com/), in which you may parameter which parts of the computer one of the apps will only use inside a sandbox.